# Why does test for Conditional Rendering not fail?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a typescript react component, that should not show a number if it is undefined or zero:

```
import * as React from "react";

export class NoZero extends React.Component<{ number?: number }, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.number && this.props.number > 0 && <div className="number">{this.props.number}</div>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The component has a Bug, that it shows in the Browser the 0. In case of the 0 we got `0 && false` which is `0` and not false, so the `<div>` with the number is rendered in the Browser. It had to be `this.props.number !== undefined && this.props.number > 0 && ...`.

This component has a mocha Test with enzymes shallow:

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import "mocha";
import * as React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { NoZero } from "./NoZero";

describe("NoZero", () => {
    it("should show not undefined", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<NoZero number={undefined} />);

        expect(wrapper.find(".number")).to.have.length(0);
    });

    it("should not show '0'", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<NoZero number={0}/>);

        expect(wrapper.find(".number")).to.have.length(0);
    });

    it("should show other numbers", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<NoZero number={2} />);

        expect(wrapper.find(".number")).to.have.length(1);
    });
});
```

This Tests are all success. Why does the second Test not fail, if the Browser shows the 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `&&` works. It returns first falsy operand

```js
console.log(0 && true)
console.log(true && 0)
```

So it renders '0' text node inside your div because `0` is falsy.

```
<div>0</div>
```

But your test check for inner `div.number` which is absent.

```
it("should not show '0'", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<NoZero number={0}/>);

    // should fail
    expect(wrapper.html()).to.equal('<div></div>');
});
```